# How to Solve Dependency Error in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am new in maven, I am getting this error while adding dependency in pom.xml file. Below is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm.jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm.jar</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jersey-bundle.jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle.jar</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>json.jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>json.jar</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jersey-core.jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core.jar</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jersey-bundle</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

For every dependency the error is shown that

```
Missing artifact json.jar:json.jar:jar:20140107
Missing artifact asm.jar:asm.jar:jar:3.3.1
Missing artifact jersey-bundle.jar:jersey-bundle.jar:jar:1.18.1
Missing artifact jersey-bundle:jersey-bundle:jar:1.18.1
Missing artifact jersey-core.jar:jersey-core.jar:jar:1.18.1
```

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you can't put the name of the jar directly.
groupId refers to "packages" most of the time and artifactId to the name of the dependency.
To have an example, go to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/1.18.3

Comment: vincent : Thanks for your quick reply.. Your solution worked, it removed the error from pom.xml but the project is showing error, though none of its component like resource or xml file contains any error. Can you pls suggest what may be causing this? I trie dby cleaning the project, but it didn't work.

Comment: no error is shown, only project is shown with red cross sign

Comment: in this case, if you use eclipse, there's probably a message in the "problems" view, no ?

Comment: I don't get you, would you be more specific? where can I found the problem view? there is not any in the console

Comment: In the Markers tab, it shows project configuration not up to date with pom.xml. And I updated the project by running Maven -> Update project and it solved my problem. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://search.maven.org/ to find the right coordinates of the dependencies ( i.e groupId + artifactId + version ).
If you have these jars already on your system, you can use http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav SHA1 with checksum, and it'll give you the matching coordinates (if available in Maven Central of course).

Answer (score 0):

in .m2 directory placed `setting.xml`, where your can declare repositories where dependecy jars should be find.

```
<settings>
 ...
 <profiles>
   ...
   <profile>
     <id>myprofile</id>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>my-repo2</id>
         <name>your custom repo</name>
         <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
   ...
 </profiles>

 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
 ...
</settings>
```

and mirror example

```
  <mirrors>
    <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository.
     | The repository that this mirror serves has an ID that matches the
     | mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used for inheritance and direct
     | lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
     -->
  </mirrors>
```

for more information look [here](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-settings/settings.html)