# how to resolve the project build error : non parseable POM error to install maven dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

how to resolve the project build error : non parseable POM error to install maven dependencies[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAMOK.png)

Comment: Run a build (like `mvn clean package`) and report the errors you get here. Do not post images of POMs.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

These are the error related to dependent file not found. You can install or add it to your config file.
[How to Solve Dependency Error in pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011972/how-to-solve-dependency-error-in-pom-xml)